# ASP.NET Core - Call controller method in javascript without Ajax

Tags: javascript, controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd like to call the method "EditProject" of my controller "Project" with a parameter being the Id of the project.

I've seen many people using Ajax, but the problem is I'd like to call the controller which in turn will redirect the user to the View "EditProject", I don't want to stay on the same page

Here is the code I've tried before figuring out it doesn't work :

```js
$('.edit-project').click(function (d) {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-projectId');

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("EditProject", "Project")',
        data: { id: id },
        type: "GET"
    }).done(function() {
        console.log("Done");
    });
    return false;
});
```

I've also tried simply using

```
$.get("/Project/EditProject/" +id); 
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("EditProject", "Project")' + '/' + id;
window.location.href = ("/Project/EditProject/" +id);
```

but it returns a 404 error.

The method called is very simple :

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = "Professional")]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditProject(int id)
{
    Project p = await _unitOfWork.Projects.GetById(id);
     ViewData["Title"] = "Modification du challenge " + p.ProjectName;
     return View(p);
}
```

And as expected with Ajax, it does return the View, but it returns it as a response to the ajax query, and thus it doesn't redirect and show the View as I would like.

Comment: Is this a typo `$.get("/Project/EditProject/ +id");` did you mean `$.get("/Project/EditProject/" +id);`

Comment: It looks to me like it just needs `window.location.href = "/Project/EditProject/" + id;`

Comment: Yes it was a typo, I've also tried the window.location.href, but it actually never calls the method from the controller. I've tried putting a breakpoint, and it never stops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply want to redirect there instead.

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("EditProject", "Project")' + '/' + id
```

There may be an MVC way to pass your id to `@Url.Action` but I'm not too familiar with it - string concatenation should work.

The controller is possibly not understanding what `/1` means. You may have to change it to the following:

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "EditProject")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Professional")]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditProject([FromRoute] int id)
{
    Project p = await _unitOfWork.Projects.GetById(id);
     ViewData["Title"] = "Modification du challenge " + p.ProjectName;
     return View(p);
}
```

This tells MVC to expect your parameter to come from the route.

Comment: It appears to not call the method from the Controller, my debug doesn't stop at the breakpoint inside, and I'm entirely sure there's no typo in the method name

Comment: Does the browser actually navigate somewhere when you trigger the click handler?

Comment: It does, it goes to https://localhost:44311/Project/EditProject/1 which is technically what I want, except it doesn't call the controller for some reason?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("EditProject", "Project",new { id = ID })';
```

you don't have to change your Action method routing if your default routing is alright.